# splitting values of a row into column in BQ but other column values should repeated

Tags: split, repeat, bq

I have a table like below -

| Project | Col-A | Col-B | Col-C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | a,b,c,d | e,f | g |
| B | d,e | a,b,c | f |

& output I want as -

| Project | Col-A | Col-B | Col-C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | a | e | g |
| A | b | f | null |
| A | c | null | null |
| A | d | null | null |
| B | d | a | f |
| B | e | b | null |
| B | null | c | null |

I used split function, though the output seems same, but project name isn't repeated for every row (it's blank) & for other columns also it's coming blank instead of null. that's why I can't download the result. it gives me error - "Schema is not flat - cannot save to selected destination."

So for a specific project , maximum number of values present in any of the column will be the max row number in the output. Please help me with the query.